# Pauli matrices in the Heisenberg picture

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, operators

So, take for instance the x and y pauli matrices $\sigma_1$ and $\sigma_2$, which have a representation in the $\sigma_3$ basis as

$$
\sigma_1 =
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 1 \\
1 & 0
\end{pmatrix},\ \
\sigma_2 = 
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & -i \\
i & 0
\end{pmatrix}
$$

Now consider dynamic evolution given by a Hamiltonian like $H = \lambda\sigma_3$. In the Heisenberg picture, $\sigma_1$ and $\sigma_2$ become time-dependent operators, whose time derivatives are

$$
\frac{d \sigma_1}{d t} \propto \sigma_2,\ \ \ \frac{d \sigma_2}{d t} \propto \sigma_1
$$

Now, clearly the above matrix form for $\sigma_1$ and $\sigma_2$ (which I've always kinda taken as a definition) becomes inappropriate, since all its elements are constant numbers.

My question is: how do I integrate these equations to obtain the 4 time-dependent elements of each matrix?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Integrating your equations is a bit silly. You just evaluate
$$
\sigma_1(t) \equiv e^{-i\theta \sigma_3} \sigma_1 e^{i\theta \sigma_3}\\
\sigma_2(t) \equiv e^{-i\theta \sigma_3} \sigma_2 e^{i\theta \sigma_3} ,
$$
with $\theta\equiv t\lambda/\hbar$.

But Pauli vectors exponentiate [trivially](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pauli_matrices#Exponential_of_a_Pauli_vector),
$$
e^{i\theta \sigma_3} =\cos \theta +i \sigma_3 \sin\theta ,
$$
whence you just evaluate,
$$
\sigma_1(t)= \sigma_1 \cos (2\theta) + \sigma_2\sin(2\theta) ,\\
\sigma_2(t)= \sigma_2 \cos (2\theta) - \sigma_1\sin(2\theta),
$$
a uniform rotation, as you'd expect (why?).

Comment: Thank you! For some reason I had forgotten about the time evolution operator. I take it the uniform rotation of $\sigma_1$ and $\sigma_2$ is the Heisenberg picture statement of the Larmor precession, right?

Comment: Basically. Rotation round the z-axis.